# Telerik upload multiple target folders

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I've had a quick look through telerik's documentation and a search on here hasn't brought anything up.

Basically I'm after a single image to be uploaded to multiple folders using telerik's upload control. I know I can do this with asp:fileupload and that's the method I would normally use but I'm fed up of having one and a half thousand pounds worth of software and I never use any of the controls available :P

```
        <telerik:RadUpload ID="RadFeature1Image" runat="server" 
                           ControlObjectsVisibility="None" 
            TargetFolder="/content/img/portfolio/">
        </telerik:RadUpload>
```

That's my current code and it works fine basically what I'm after is to allow more than one target folder. Now I know with telerik's products in the past you could just comma separate the values but that shows an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible; however, from the [examples](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-manipulating-files.html) page:

```
  foreach (UploadedFile f in RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
  {
      f.SaveAs( "c:\\uploaded files\\" + f.GetName(), true);
      //You could copy the file to the other folders you have in mind here, or call f.SaveAs again or similar...
  }
```

I like Telerik's controls a lot but I haven't seen the UploadControl work with multiple target folders before - I have performed a copy to another folder using code similar to the example above, however.

Comment: yeah as I thought. I'd seen something similar in telerik's documentation as well I just liked the autosave function. Shame that they're omitted this functionality. Thanks for quick reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as follows; according to the telerik support [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/save-single-file-to-mutiple-target-folder).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UploadedFile file in RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("Files");
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);

        string copiesPath = Server.MapPath("Copies");
        string copiesFullPath = Path.Combine(copiesPath, file.FileName);

        file.SaveAs(fullPath);
        File.Copy(fullPath, copiesFullPath);
    }
}
```